# Compare Values from Two Columns of Data Set

Tags: r

I'm new to R and keep trying to think of it like JS, but it's definitely nothing like it. I need to take each value in column 1 and compare it to it's counter part in column 2.

For example: If the fifth item in column 1 is "Subaru" I need to see what the fifth item in column 2 is. If in column 2 the zip code is 24153, do one thing, if it's 24060 do something else.

With JS I would just run a for loop and do something like

```
for(i; i < name.length; i++){
    if(name[i] == "Subaru" && zipcode[i] == 24153){
        do this
    } else if (blah blah){
        blah blah blah
    }
}
```

But you can't use i to get the index of each column in R because in an R for loop i is the value...right?

I tried nesting for loops but I have 7,000+ items in the database and cycling through all those twice is killer, even with breaks because the inner loop always starts back at 1.

I tried also putting them in a list but for some reason that's not working. Here are the two methods I've tried so far.

```
names = data$model
zips = data$zipcode
mylist <- list()
mylist[[1]] <- names
mylist[[2]] <- zips

r = 0
while (r <= length(mylist[[1]])) {
  print(mylist[[1]][r])
  print(mylist[[2]][r])
  if(!is.na(mylist[[1]][r])){
    if(mylist[[1]][r] == "Subaru" & mylist[[2]][r] == "24153"){
      print(mylist[[1]][r])
    }
  }
}
```

And the nested for loops

```
  names = data$model
  zips = data$zipcode
  for (j in names) {
  if(!is.na(j)){
    for (k in zips) {
      if(!is.na(k)){
        if(j == "Subaru" & k == "24153"){
          print(j)
          break
        } else if(j == "Subaru" & k == "24060"){
          print(j)
          break
        } else if(j == "Subaru" & k == "24019"){
          print(j)
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any tips or ideas are welcome. I feel like I'm looking at it the wrong way.

Comment: what's the conditions you wanted to check, and what's your expected outcome?

Comment: Is `print`ing really your goal? If your result is a vector, then vectorized `ifelse()` is what you want, if you actually want to "do something", then another approach might make sense. Please describe your goal, not just your method.

Comment: *"you can't use i to get the index of each column in R because in an R for loop i is the value...right?"* R gives you the choice, you can loop over values or indices. You have `for (j in names)`, but you could easily do `for (j in 1:length(names))` instead, and use `names[j]` inside the loop where you currently have `j`, and use the index `j` for other things too.

Comment: For example, one other approach might be to subset your data of interest: `data_interest = subset(data, model == "Subaru" & zipcode %in% c("24153", "24060", "24019"))`, and then iterate just over that subset to "do something", but there's probably a better way.

Comment: Can you give us 1) a sample of the dataframe[df] you have? `dput(head(df))` will get you a little sample to start with. Then 2) show us what you want the dataframe to look like when it is 'finished'? With this format we should be able to come up with many, probably simpler approaches than you are currently envisioning. For example: I am wondering if you aren't just in search of a `join` operation.

Comment: @Gregor, print is not my end goal, just a means to see if it is working. Thanks for the looping tip. I will try that!

Comment: Right, of course printing isn't your goal. I'm trying to tell you that the best approach *will depend on your actual goal*. Please share your end goal so that we can help you find the best approach, whether it be `ifelse`, operating on a subset of the data, or something else. Otherwise we are [stuck with an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/173584).

Comment: The end goal is to find where one column equals "Subaru" (or other manufacturer) and another equals a certain zip code. Then tag "Subaru" in column one with -H1. Another specified pairing would be -H2, -H3, etc. This is just an exercise for school so it probably isn't super realistic for real world comparisons.

Comment: Oh man, I just realized I've been doing it 100% wrong. I should have just been doing a gsub(). Everything is fine now, learned the hard way. Two days down the drain, but at least I won't make that mistake ever again. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your for loop is in more of a java format. Try something like this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data){
    if(name[i] == "Subaru" & zipcode[i] == 24153){
        foo
    }else if{
        bar
}}
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to do, but ultimately I went with a gsub() method.